# azure data factory recursive copy from container

Tags: azure, recursion, copy, azure-data-factory

Hi I am using Azure Data Factory for a Copy activity.
I want the copy to be recursive across a container and it subfolders as follows:
myfolder/Year/Month/Day/Hour}/New_Generated_File.csv

The files that I am generating and importing into the folder have always a different name.

The problem is that activity seems to waiting for ever.

The pipeline is scheduled hourly.

I'm attaching the json code of the dataset and the linked service.

Dataset:

```
{
"name": "Txns_In_Blob",
"properties": {
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "Column0",
            "type": "String"
        },
        [....Other Columns....]
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "LinkedService_To_Blob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "uploadtransactional/yearno={Year}/monthno={Month}/dayno={Day}/hourno={Hour}/{Custom}.csv",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "rowDelimiter": "\n",
            "columnDelimiter": "    "
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

}

Linked Service:

```
{
"name": "LinkedService_To_Blob",
"properties": {
    "description": "",
    "hubName": "dataorchestrationsystem_hub",
    "type": "AzureStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=wizestorage;AccountKey=**********"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mandatory to give the file name in the dataset's `folderPath` property. Just remove the file name and then all the files will be loaded by the datafactory for you.

```
{
  "name": "Txns_In_Blob",
  "properties": {
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "Column0",
            "type": "String"
        },
        [....Other Columns....]
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "LinkedService_To_Blob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "folderPath": "uploadtransactional/yearno={Year}/monthno={Month}/dayno={Day}/hourno={Hour}/",
        "partitionedBy": [
            { "name": "Year", "value": { "type": "DateTime", "date": "SliceStart", "format": "yyyy" } },
            { "name": "Month", "value": { "type": "DateTime", "date": "SliceStart", "format": "%M" } },
            { "name": "Day", "value": { "type": "DateTime", "date": "SliceStart", "format": "%d" } },
            { "name": "Hour", "value": { "type": "DateTime", "date": "SliceStart", "format": "hh" } }
        ],
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "rowDelimiter": "\n",
            "columnDelimiter": "    "
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 1
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

With the above `folderPath` it will generate the run time value 
`uploadtransactional/yearno=2016/monthno=05/dayno=30/hourno=07/` for a pipeline which executes UTC time zone now

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you say is correct and I've tried that too but why the pipeline is waiting forever? I've checked the parameter "external" is set on false. I'm getting this error: Blob https://wizestorage.blob.core.windows.net/upl/yearno={Year}/monthno={Month}/dayno={Day}/hourno={Hour}/ does not exist

It seems that it's not converting the script into the actual path.

Comment: Did you define the logic to assign values to `{Hour} {Year}` etc?

Comment: If the dataset is marked as external then the pipeline will execute immediately. If it is set to false then it will keep waiting till some **_other pipeline produces_** the dataset

Comment: Thanks Sandesh you are great. How do you define the logic to assign the values to {Hour} {Year} etc?

Comment: I have already updated the answer to provide the logic for assigning the value for {Hour} and others